# Proof of a new Log Gamma Formula in the context of a Laplace transform of a digamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, several-complex-variables

**Introduction:**
With the long introduction I want to provide the context, include the source and motivation for my question to the community.

Interest in this question began with curiosity about a different form of a new identity [stocha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407611/a-more-general-closed-form-of-an-integral-involving-a-square-power-of-theta-4)

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}\left( \beta \right) = \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\beta}{1+\beta^2\,x^{2}}~\theta _{4}^{2}\left( \exp \left( -\pi \,x\right)\right) \,dx\text{,} \qquad  \mathcal{I}\left(1\right) = 1\text{,}   \label{eq:rzwei}
\end{align}

using the "evaluating integrals over the positive real axis" property of the Laplace transform [WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) and e.g. [Glasser](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/23644070_Some_Integrals_of_the_Dedekind_Eta-function). This property, as will be seen, can be used to derive the following different form of the same identity:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}\left( \beta \right) = \frac{\pi }{2}+\int_0^{\infty } (\psi (1+i\, x)+\psi (1-i\,x))\, \left(\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi\,  x}{\beta }\right)-2\,\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi\,  x}{\beta }\right)\right) \, dx-\beta\log(2)\text{,} \label{eq:rdrei}
\end{align}

which is surprisingly related to the sum over the Laplace transform of the complex valued digamma function:

\begin{align}
P_{C} = \int_0^{\infty }sech(\lambda \,x) \, \psi (1\pm i \,x) \, dx = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \times \label{eq:rvier}
\end{align}

\begin{equation*}
\times\int_0^{\infty }e^{-\lambda\,(2\,k+1)\, x} \, \psi (1\pm i \,x) \, dx \quad\text{for}\quad \lambda=\frac{2 \,\pi \, x}{\beta }\, \text{,} \qquad \lambda=\frac{\pi \, x}{\beta }\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where we used the known series expansion of $sech(x)$ and two different $\lambda$.

An explicit formula for the Laplace transform of the real valued digamma function is discussed in
[Dixit](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243066953_The_Laplace_transform_of_the_psi_function) in
the context of the famous integral [OLIVIER OLOA](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5ecb/1e63244ceefecf19aa9c94bfd707360b3e48.pdf)

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{\theta^2}{\theta^2+\log (2\, \cos (\theta ))} \, d\theta = \frac{1}{8} \pi \, (1+\log (2 \,\pi )-\gamma )
\end{equation}

**Laplace transform of the complex valued digamma function**:
In the present post we give an explicit expression for the Laplace transform of a complex valued digamma function (the long prove is skipped here):

> **Propositon:**
> Let $a > 0$,  $\gamma$  the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi\left(i\,x\right)$ the complex valued digamma function, then \begin{align}
> L_{C}(a)= \int_0^{\infty } e^{-a z} \psi (1+i\,x) \, dx = 2\,a \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\log (n) }{a^2-4 n^2 \pi ^2} -\frac{\gamma +\log\left(a\right) }{a} + \label{eq:rfuenfzehn}
> \end{align} \begin{equation*}
> \left(\frac{1}{2} \cot \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{a}\right) \log \left(\frac{2 \pi }{a}\right)+\frac{\pi }{4}+
> \frac{i}{2}\left(\log \left(\frac{a}{2 \pi }\right)-\psi \left(\frac{a}{2 \pi }\right)-\frac{\pi }{a}\right)
> \end{equation*}

The expression for $L_{C}(a)$ is explicitly given in the form of a real - and imaginary part: \begin{align}
L_{C}(a)= \Re(L_{C}(a))+i\,\Im(L_{C}(a)) \label{eq:rsechzehn}\text{.}
\end{align}

$\Im(L_{C}(a))$ - the last term describes the imaginary part of and is explicitly given in a closed form:
\begin{align}
\Im(L_{C}(a))= \frac{1}{2}\left(\log \left(\frac{a}{2 \pi }\right)-\psi \left(\frac{a}{2 \pi }\right)-\frac{\pi }{a}\right) \label{eq:rsiebzehn}
\end{align}

A further important property is given:

> **Conjecture:**
> For a complex number $a=i\,y$ we have: \begin{align}
> \Re(L_{C}(i\,y)) = 0 \text{,}\qquad \underset{a\to \,i\,y}{\Re\left(\Re(L_{C}(a))\right)}=\Re\left(\Im(L_{C}(i\,y))\right) \label{eq:rvierundfuenfzig}
> \end{align}

This property ends up in the next Propositon:

> **Propositon:** If $z > 0$, then
> \begin{align}
> \Im(\psi(i\, z))=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\coth (\pi \, z)+\frac{1}{\pi \, z}\right)\text{,}\qquad \Im(\psi(1+i\, z))=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\coth (\pi \, z)-\frac{1}{\pi \, z}\right) \label{eq:reinundzwanzig}
> \end{align}

This identity was already published and proved [Raymond Manzoni](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234855/how-to-calculate-re-psi-mathrmiy-and-im-psi-mathrmiy-frac12y), but there in the context of the  reflection formula.
In the following we consider $a=i\,z$ a complex number. We substitute Euler's formula
\begin{equation}
e^{-i\, t\, z}=\cos (t\, z)-i\, \sin (t\, z)
\end{equation}
in $L_{C}(a)$ and split it in two integrals. We assumed a close solution for the first integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty } \psi (1+i\, t) \cos (t \,z) \, dt = -\frac{i}{2} \left(\frac{1}{\frac{2\, (-i \,z)}{2\, \pi }}-\log \left(-\frac{i\, z}{2\, \pi }\right)+\psi\left(-\frac{i\, z}{2 \pi }\right)\right)
\end{equation}
The integral involving a real valued digamma function exists, too. It is given in a closed form, too:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^{\infty } \psi \left(1+\frac{t}{2  \,\pi }\right) \cos (t \,z) \, dt = \frac{1}{2\, z}-\log(z)+\psi (z)
\end{equation}

We Integrate over z and evaluate the constant of integration, without proving it:
\begin{equation}
c = \frac{1}{2}\,(\gamma +\log (2 \pi ))
\end{equation}

Finally we get the new log gamma formula:

> **Propositon:** A formula for $\log (\Gamma (z))$ for $\Re((z)>0$ is
> \begin{align}
> \log (\Gamma (z))=\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log(z)-z+\frac{1}{2}\,(\gamma +\log (2 \pi ))+\frac{1}{\pi}\,\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (t z)}{t}\psi\left(1+\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)\, dt\text{,} \label{eq:reins}
> \end{align}
> where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

In other words, the formula means, that we have a closed form solution of the last integral (Proposition).

We note, that in contrast to Binet's Log Gamma Formulas [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html), that the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ appear like in the solution of the famous [OLIVIER OLOA](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5ecb/1e63244ceefecf19aa9c94bfd707360b3e48.pdf) integral.

My attempt was also to start from the Binet's second formula [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html)
\begin{equation}
\psi(z)=log (z)-\frac{1}{2\, z}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{t\, (\coth (\pi\, t)-1)}{t^2+z^2} \, dt
\end{equation}

and use the  "evaluating integrals over the positive real axis" property of the Laplace transform [WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)
and well known formula: $\psi (x+1)=\frac{1}{x}+\psi (x)$ to get:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi }\,\int_0^{\infty } \left(\psi \left(1+\frac{t}{2\, \pi }\right)+\gamma \right) \cos (t\, z) \, dt=\frac{1}{2\, z}-\log z)+\psi(z)
\end{equation}

I did not finished this way strictly and found the log gamma formula by try and error.

> **Question:**
>
> 1. How can we proof the new formula for the $\log (\Gamma (z))$ explicitely?
> 2. Is there a relation between the new integral and the Glasser-Manna-Oloa integral and what is the relation?

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate the integral term of the formula
\begin{equation}
I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (t z)}{t}\psi\left(1+\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)\, dt
\end{equation}
we use the representation [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7.E6)
\begin{equation}
\psi\left(1+\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)=-\gamma+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t}{n(n+t/2\pi)}
\end{equation} 
Then
\begin{equation}
I=-\frac{1}{2}\gamma+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (t z)}{2\pi n+t}\,dt
\end{equation} 
Now, using the Laplace transform method for evaluating integrals [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) on the real axis as proposed in the OP , with
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\left[\sin t z\right]=\frac{z}{u^2+z^2}\quad ;\quad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{2\pi n+t}\right]=e^{-2\pi nu}
\end{equation} 
we obtain
\begin{align}
I&=-\frac{1}{2}\gamma+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z}{n}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2\pi nu}}{u^2+z^2}\,du\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\gamma-\frac{z}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left( 1-e^{-2\pi u} \right)}{u^2+z^2}\,du
\end{align} 
Integrating by parts, 
\begin{equation}
I=-\frac{1}{2}\gamma+2\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan (u/z)}{e^{2\pi u}-1}\,du
\end{equation} 
From the Binet's second formula
\begin{equation}
\ln\left( \Gamma(z) \right)=\left( z-\frac{1}{2} \right)\ln z-z+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left( 2\pi \right)+2\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan \left( t/z \right)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\,dt
\end{equation} 
we have
\begin{equation}
I=-\frac{1}{2}\gamma-\left( z-\frac{1}{2} \right)\ln z+z-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left( 2 \pi \right)+\ln\left( \Gamma(z) \right)
\end{equation} 
And thus
\begin{equation}
\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log(z)-z+\frac{1}{2}\,(\gamma +\log (2 \pi ))+I=\ln\left( \Gamma(z) \right)
\end{equation} 
as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the proof, for the second question I have already an idea and your derivation gives me the inside I need.

Comment: I am pleased to see you can use it. I'll be interested in the answer to the second question.

Comment: When I have it, I will add it on this side.