# Integral of combined exponential, trigonometric, and polynomial functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm reading a paper which therein the author claims:

$$\int_0^\infty dx \frac{e^{-m^2 x}}{x^2} \left[a x \cot (a x) - 1\right] = a K \left(\frac{i m^2}{2 a}\right)$$

where $m$ and $a$ are real, and

$$K(z) = 2 i \left[\left(z - \frac{1}{2}\right)\log z - z - \log \Gamma(z) + \frac{1}{2} \log 2 \pi\right]$$

How can one verify this?

I tried to investigate it numerically, which it seems to be correct. For example, for $m = 4$ and $a = 3$, Mathematica returns $-0.18842$ for the integral, and $-0.18842 - i 1.5865 \cdot 10^{-7}$ for the right hand side. For other values of $m$ and $a$, it seems one should consider the real part of the function $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To long for a comment. $K(z)$ is related to the Binet's Log Gamma Formulas [Binet's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html), where only the factor $2\,i$ is different. The relation of the integral in the Binet' formulas and your's have to be shown.
EDIT:
I tried to show the relation and proof the identity:

$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-tz} \left(\frac{t}{2} \cot \
\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-1\right)}{t^2} \, dt=-2 \int_0^{\infty } \
\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{z}\right)}{e^{2
\pi  t}-1} \, dt$  for $z=\frac{m^2}{2a}$

Numerical experiment show, that the right hand side is just an approximation of the left hand side for $z>>1$. In other words your solution is only an approximation.

**Proof of the identity**

The statement above is not correct, I managed to find the proof of the identity.

We start with the identity above:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-m^2 x} (a x \cot (a x)-1)}{x^2} \, dx=a \
K\left[\frac{i\, m^2}{2 a}\right]$$

with

$$K(z)=2 i \left(\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (z)-z-\log (\Gamma \
(z))+\frac{1}{2} \,\log (2\, \pi )\right)$$

1. Variable substitution:

Set: $y = 2 \,a\, x$ and $z=\frac{i\,m^2}{2\,a}$

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{2\, a \,\left(\frac{y}{2} \,\cot \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-1\right) e^{i\,z\,y}}{y^2}\, dy=2\,a\, i \left(\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (z)-z-\log (\Gamma \
(z))+\frac{1}{2} \,\log (2\, \pi )\right)$$

2. Differentiation

Differentiate both sides with respect to z:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{i\, y \,z} \left(\frac{y}{2}\, \cot\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-1\right)}{y} \, dy=-\frac{1}{2 z}+\log \
(z)-\psi(z)$$

where $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function.

3.) Redefine z

It is easier to go further with $w=\frac{z}{i}$

4.) Integration

We split the indefinite integral in two parts:

$$\int \frac{e^{-w\, y} \left(\frac{y}{2}  \cot \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-1\right)}{y} \, dy=\frac{1}{2} \int e^{-w \,y} \cot \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\, dy-\int \frac{e^{-w\, y}}{y} \, dy$$

and substitute the integration limits later. The first Integral is just the half of the Laplace-Transform of ${\cot \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}$. The last integral is the well known ExpIntegraE - Function $\text{Ei}(-w\, y)$. 
The first integral can also alternatively done with Mathematica:

$$\frac{1}{2} \int e^{-w\, y} \cot \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \, \
dy=-\,\frac{1}{2} \left(B_{e^{i\, y}}(1+i\, w,0) + B_{e^{i\, y}}(i\, w,0)\right)$$

where $B_z(a,b)$ is the Euler beta function. One can proof that by differentiation.

5.) Insertion of integration limits

If we insert the integration limits we finally get:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-w\, y} \left(\frac{y}{2} \cot\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-1\right)}{y} \, dy= -\, \frac{1}{2} \left(\log\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)-\log(-z)+\psi(1+i\, z)+\psi(i\, z)-i \,\pi \right)$$

Further simplification and using:

$$\frac{1}{2} \psi(1+i\, z)+\frac{\psi(i \,z)}{2}=\psi(i\, w)-\frac{i}{2\, w}$$
leads to the postulate identity.

Comment: Many thanks. Could you elaborate how have you obtained the identity?

Comment: And also, why is it an approximation? Do you mean Binet's formula is an approximation?

Comment: Sorry, I already finished the exact proof of your identity- I was wrong with the approximation. I had an appointment and did not post it until now, I will do it in the next 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks. So, this means that the integral identity that you have written before your section "proof of the identity" should be valid. How can one prove that?

Comment: I will finish in 10 minutes

Comment: I took a little bit longer, this should help to understand the prove

Comment: You had another question, but then the question was deleted?

Comment: Many thanks. It's more or less understandable for me. So that this identity is exact, the integral identity that you wrote before editing your answer: $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-tz} \left(\frac{t}{2} \cot \
\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-1\right)}{t^2} \, dt=-2 \int_0^{\infty } \
\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{z}\right)}{e^{2
\pi  t}-1} \, dt$  for $z=\frac{m^2}{2a}$ should hold for all $z$. But Mathematica for some values does not confirm this statement.

Comment: That is correct. For some values $z<=1$ Mathematica does not calculate the correct value! That why I first come to  a wrong conclusion, that this is only an approximation.

Comment: I had asked another question regarding log-gamma functions. Could you also help on that?

Comment: I read it an I think my post [stocha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348684/proof-of-a-new-log-gamma-formula-in-the-context-of-a-laplace-transform-of-a-diga)

Comment: I read it an I think $\Im(\psi(i\, z))=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\coth (\pi \, z)+\frac{1}{\pi \, z}\right)$ [stocha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348684/proof-of-a-new-log-gamma-formula-in-the-context-of-a-laplace-transform-of-a-diga) and $\frac{\partial \log (\Gamma (z))}{\partial z}=\psi(z)$ should investigated in a more detail.

Comment: Thanks. I need time to understand your post.

Comment: Later, in coming days, if you had time that would be grate if you could write an answer also to that question.

Comment: Yes, on Saturday / Sunday I have time and will have a look on your question.

Comment: Thanks for that!