# Real and imaginary parts of $\ln \Gamma(i b)$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function, digamma-function

Can one obtain the real and imaginary parts of $\ln \Gamma (i b)$ in terms of simpler functions?

($b$ is a positive number.)

Comment: I would more likely expect a relationship with the complex conjugate, not the imaginary part. What makes you think such a relationship would exist?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I don't know that if such a thing exists. I just needed that to simplify my calculations.

Comment: "your calculations" ? We fully understand $|\Gamma(it)|$ from $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)= \pi / \sin \pi s$, to understand $\Im \log \Gamma(it)$ we need more, the explicit formula for $\Gamma'/\Gamma$ and its approximation, ie. Stirling approximation.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your comment. I am trying to solve a problem in physics which resulted in some terms including $\ln \Gamma(i b)$. To solve the resulting equations I need to separate the real and imaginary parts of the terms. My problem is that I cannot figure this out for  $\ln \Gamma(i b)$.

Comment: @reuns I'm trying to figure out your hints. How is the imaginary part of $\log \Gamma(it)$ related to $\Gamma^' / \Gamma$?

Comment: Reuns said the absolute value is related. There is no obvious relationship between $\Gamma(ib)$ and $\Gamma(b)$ so your best bet is expanding via simpler functions, e.g. the Stirling Approximation

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the derivation we need the formular for $\Im(\psi(i\, z))$ and

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty } \psi (1+i\, t) \cos (t \,z) \, dt = -\frac{i}{2} \left(\frac{1}{\frac{2\, (-i \,z)}{2\, \pi }}-\log \left(-\frac{i\, z}{2\, \pi }\right)+\psi\left(-\frac{i\, z}{2 \pi }\right)\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\frac{i}{2} \,\log \left(\frac{z}{2 \pi }\right)-\frac{\pi }{4} \
\left(\coth \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)-1\right)-\frac{i}{4}  \
\left(\psi\left(1-\frac{iz}{2 \pi }\right)+\psi\left(1+\frac{i z}{2 \pi }\right)\right)
\end{equation}
[stocha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348684/proof-of-a-new-log-gamma-formula-in-the-context-of-a-laplace-transform-of-a-diga) and [A Man Called Old Fashion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386060/integral-of-combined-exponential-trigonometric-and-polynomial-functions/3386644#3386644), where the right hand side is explicitely given in a real - and imaginary part in a closed form. The complete proof of the following proposition is very extensive and time-consuming, we just state the result here.

> **Propositon:** If $z > 0$, then
>   \begin{align}
> \Re(\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))=\frac{1}{2} (\log (\Gamma (-i\, b))+\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))=\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(\frac{\pi }{b}\right)-\log (\sinh(\pi\,  b))\right)
> \end{align}
>   \begin{align}
> \Im(\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))=\frac{i}{2}\,(\log(\Gamma (1-i\,b))-\log (\Gamma (1+i\,b)))-\frac{\pi }{2}
> \end{align}
>   \begin{align}
> =\frac{i}{2}\, (\log (\Gamma (-i\, b))-\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))
> \end{align}

The second identity of the real part results immediately from
\begin{align}
\Gamma (z)\, \Gamma (-z)=-\frac{\pi }{z\, \sin (\pi \, z)}
\end{align}

Comment: Great! I understand the real part, but the imaginary part is not completely reduced, and what is $y$?

Comment: The real part is beautiful and concise. But, the imaginary part still has $\ln \Gamma$. Is it possible to reduce that?

Comment: For b = 1/2 I got -1.81485 for the imaginary part on both sides. This is the result of the already derivated equations, I think that furher reduction is difficult.

Comment: Do you have any idea how theoretically one can reduce it?

Comment: Maybe use the result of the real part, by extending the argument of the $\log\Gamma$

Comment: I have to thing about it

Comment: Perhaps, $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$?

Comment: One has to express $\Im(\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))$ by $\Re(\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))$ to get a reduction

Comment: I'm trying to reduce it by using $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$, if you could come up with something, please share it!

Comment: The ansatz just gives, $\Im(\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))=\frac{i}{2} (\log (\Gamma (-i\, b))-\log (\Gamma (i\, b)))$ no more reduction

Comment: but I think the real part is not posted until now

Comment: I think that's true!

Comment: Somehow $ \frac{\Gamma (-i\,b)} {\Gamma (b)}$  cannot be simplified, because of the complex argument. I think the imaginary part cannot be reduced more.